# Как правильно подставить url адрес до изображения?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Написал тренировочный Vue компонент с шаблоном. В шаблоне использовал шаблонные литералы и возникла проблема с подстановкой url адреса до изображения. 
Перепробовал разные варианты, но решить проблему так и не смог.

Как в моем случае подставить адрес до изображения взятый из объекта?

```
<img src="{{comment.comment_image}}"/>
```

```js
let queryComments = [{
    comment_id: 1,
    comment_image: '//loremflickr.com/100/100',
    comment_description: 'Looks great Julianne!',
  },
  {
    comment_id: 2,
    comment_image: '//loremflickr.com/100/100',
    comment_description: 'I love the sea',
  },
  {
    comment_id: 3,
    comment_image: '//loremflickr.com/100/100',
    comment_description: 'Where are you at?',
  }
];

Vue.component('template_comment', {
  props: ['comment'],
  template: `<li>
   <img src="{{comment.comment_image}}"/>
   <div>id: {{comment.comment_id}}</div>
   <div>Комментарий: {{comment.comment_description}}</div>
   </li>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#comments',
  data: {
    comments: queryComments
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<ul id="comments">
  <template_comment v-for="comment in comments" v-bind:comment="comment">
  </template_comment>
</ul>
```

Comment: попробуйте `<img :src="comment.comment_image"/>`

Comment: Работает, спасибо! Отпишите в ответах, выберу Вас!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue.JS позволяет привязать данные из javascript к шаблону при помощи директивы `v-bind:src` или его сокращенной версии `:src`.
В вашем случае необходимо использовать следующую запись:
`<img :src="comment.comment_image"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Если какие-то данные должны подставляться динамически, то вы должны использовать стандартный атрибут, но с двоеточием в начале:

```
<img :src="comment.comment_image"/>
```

```js
let queryComments = [{
    comment_id: 1,
    comment_image: '//loremflickr.com/100/100',
    comment_description: 'Looks great Julianne!',
  },
  {
    comment_id: 2,
    comment_image: '//loremflickr.com/100/100',
    comment_description: 'I love the sea',
  },
  {
    comment_id: 3,
    comment_image: '//loremflickr.com/100/100',
    comment_description: 'Where are you at?',
  }
];

Vue.component('template_comment', {
  props: ['comment'],
  template: `<li>
   <img :src="comment.comment_image"/>
   <div>id: {{comment.comment_id}}</div>
   <div>Комментарий: {{comment.comment_description}}</div>
   </li>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#comments',
  data: {
    comments: queryComments
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<ul id="comments">
  <template_comment v-for="( comment, index ) in comments" v-bind:comment="comment" :key="index">
  </template_comment>
</ul>
```